# .Net Core Variable replacements in appSettings.json to reference other config values

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Imagine the following `appSettings.json` file:

```js
{
   "GlobalSettings": {
        "BaseUrl": "http://example.com:5000"
    },
    "NavigationSettings": {
        "LoginUrl": "{GlobalSettings:BaseUrl}/Login"
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to automatically replace the value of `GlobalSettings:BaseUrl` within the value of `NavigationSettings:LoginUrl`. I know one can use `appSettings.{env}.json` to override specific keys, but that overrides the *entire* value, not just part of it.

I could work around this by using an extension method something like the following, but this would require the programmer to remember to call the extension method everywhere they *might* want to have a config value replaced.

```c#
ReplaceConfigValues(this string input, IConfiguration config) { /*...*/ }
```

Can anyone suggest any alternative methods I could use, or are there some new .Net Core features I might be missing?

Even something like referencing a environment variable within the config value would be useful, but I don't know of a way to do that either. E.g.

```js
"LoginUrl": "${ENV_GLOBAL_BASE_URL}/Login"
```

Comment: Write your own method, which reads the login url, then apply regex to get all key values within the `{...}`, the read the values and replace them. Nothig magically here

Comment: @Tseng I was hoping to have something more generic, where any config value could reference any config key, but I'll probably end up going down that route if that's my best option. Cheers!

Comment: There isn't anything built-in as far as I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment from Tseng is true, there is nothing built-in yet.
I created a library for that purpose it does exactly what you expect. See: https://github.com/molinch/ConfigurationSubstitutor
You just need to register it as another configuration source.

For example if you have these three entries defined in the configuration:

- Foo = {Bar1}{Bar2}{Bar1}
- Bar1 = Barista
- Bar2 = -Jean-

When requesting Foo from the configuration you will get: `Barista-Jean-Barista`

Answer (score 0):

Try HOCON
https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md

```
{
   "GlobalSettings": {
        "BaseUrl": "http://example.com:5000"
    },
    "NavigationSettings": {
        "LoginUrl": "{GlobalSettings:BaseUrl}/Login"
    }
}
```

could be translated into

```
"GlobalSettings": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://example.com:5000"
}

"NavigationSettings": {
    "LoginUrl": "${GlobalSettings.BaseUrl}/Login"
}
```

Here's the configuration extension:
https://github.com/akkadotnet/HOCON
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hocon.Extensions.Configuration/